# Are squeezed arrays (in Python) smaller than arrays with single-dimensional entries? ([x,y] vs [x,y,1]?)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

When trying to get code to work using different frameworks and sources, I've stumbled across this multiple times:

Python Numpy arrays `A` and `B` that contentwise are the same, but one has `A.shape == [x, y]` and the other `B.shape == [x, y, 1]`. From dealing with it several times, I know that I can solve issues with this with [squeeze](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html):

```
A == numpy.squeeze(B)
```

But currently I have to redesign a lot of code that errors due to "inconsistent" arrays in that regard (some images with `len(img.shape) = 2` *[1024, 1024]* and some images with `len(img.shape) = 3` *[1024, 1024, 1]*.

Now I have to pick one and I'm leaning towards *[1024, 1024, 1]*, but since this code should be memory-efficient I'm wondering:

**Do arrays with single-dimensional entries consume more memory than squeezed arrays?** Or is there any other reason why I should avoid single-dimensional entries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do arrays with single-dimensional entries consume more memory than squeezed arrays?

#### They take the same amount of memory.

NumPy arrays have a property called [`nbytes`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.nbytes.html) that represents the number of bytes used by the array itself. Using this you can easily verify this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.ones((1024, 1024, 1))
>>> arr.nbytes
8388608
>>> arr.squeeze().nbytes
8388608
```

The reason it takes the same amount of memory is actually easy: NumPy arrays aren't real multi-dimensional arrays. They are one-dimensional arrays that use [`strides`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.strides.html) to "emulate" multidimensionality. These strides give the memory offset for a particular dimension:

```
>>> arr.strides
(8192, 8, 8)
>>> arr.squeeze().strides
(8192, 8)
```

So by removing the length-one dimension you effectively removed a zero-byte offset.

> Or is there any other reason why I should avoid single-dimensional entries?

It depends. In some cases you actually create these yourself to utilize [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) with NumPy arrays. However in some cases they are annoying.

---

Note that there is in fact a small memory difference because NumPy has to store one stride and shape integer for each dimension:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getsizeof(arr)
8388736
>>> sys.getsizeof(arr.squeeze().copy()) # remove one dimension
8388720
>>> sys.getsizeof(arr[:, None].copy())  # add one dimension
8388752
```

However 16 bytes per dimension isn't very much compared to the 8kk bytes the array takes and to a view (squeeze returns a view - that's why I had to copy it) which uses ~100 bytes.

Comment: So in practice, there is no reason to squeeze multidimensional NumPy arrays in Python?

Comment: @Triceratops Well, to remove empty dimensions. But not to save memory.

Comment: But is it necessary? For example: if I multiply matrices, does it matter if I use x[0,:,:] y[0,:,:] or np.squeeze(x[0,:,:]) ?

Comment: @Triceratops There's probably use-cases for `squeeze` otherwise the function probably wouldn't exist. I can't remember using it in production code though - but that's just my personal experience and is outside the scope of this Q+A.